# Sending input data to child process in node.js

Tags: javascript, c++, node.js, online-compilation

I am writing code to create an online c++ compiler in node.js environment.Using `spawn`  function i created a child process which will compile the code and execute it and send the output back to the user.
But i need to send input to the running c++ program . I used `child.stdin.write('data');`
for sending data to child but i think `cin` in the program is not receiving the input .

Please help me to send the input to the running c++ code.
Thanks.

Comment: just in case someone is using IPC and JSON serialization, what I observed is that it sends message from Child-to-Parent but not Parent-to-Child using `send()` function. When I used `fork` instead of `spawn`, it started sending messages in both ways.

Answer (score 4):

1.Create a file with input data.
2.Create a `ReadStream` opening input file.
3.Pipe the `ReadStream` with `childprocess.stdin`.

```
file=fs.createReadStream('input.txt',{encoding:'utf8'});
file.pipe(childprocess.stdin);
```

This worked for me .

Answer (score 2):

You should probably use either cluster, or fork if you want to pass messages... if you do this, node will setup IPC for you to be able to communicate via [process.send](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_send_message_sendhandle)

---

Alternatively, you could use a pub/sub system for communication channels (Redis works well for this), this is also your best bet if you need communications across servers.

---

Below is an example of an older work script...

```
var env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'dev';
var cluster = require("cluster");

//TODO: need to adjust to use domains for this work
process.on('uncaughtException', function (err) {
  console.error('GENERAL EXCEPTION IN %s: %s', process.env.WORKER_TYPE || 'MASTER',err);
  if (err.stack) console.error(err.stack);
  if (cluster.isWorker) {
    //process.send notifies the parent process of the error
    process.send({
      err: {
        "str": err && err.toString() || "unknown error"
        ,"message": err && err.message || null
        ,"stack": err && err.stack || null
      }
    });
  }
  process.nextTick(function(){
    process.exit(666);
  });
});


if (cluster.isMaster) startMaster();
if (cluster.isWorker) startWorker();

function startMaster() {
  createWorker("foo");
  createWorker("bar");
}

function createWorker(workerType) {
  var worker = cluster.fork({"WORKER_TYPE":workerType}); //passes environment variables to child
  worker.on('online',onOnline.bind(null, worker));
  worker.on('message',onMessage.bind(null, worker)); 
  worker.on('exit',onExit.bind(null, worker));
  worker.workerType = workerType;
  return worker; 
  // you can use worker.send() to send a message that 
  // will raise a message event in the child
}

function startWorker() {
  console.log("Running Worker: %s %s", cluster.worker.id, process.env.WORKER_TYPE);
  setTimeout(process.exit.bind(process,0), 5000); //close in 5 seconds
  //you may want to load a specific module based on WORKER_TYPE
}

function onOnline(worker) {
  console.log("Worker Online: %s %s", worker.id, worker.workerType);
  //console.log(arguments);
}

function onMessage(worker, msg) {
  if (msg.err) {
    console.warn("Error From", worker.id, worker.workerType, msg.err);
  } else {
    console.log("Message From", worker.id, worker.workerType);
  }
  //console.log(arguments);
}

function onExit(worker, code, signal) {
  console.log("Worker Exited: %s %s %s %s", worker.id, worker.workerType, code, signal);

    if (env == 'dev') {
        //for now just exit the whole thing (dev mode)
        process.nextTick(function(){
            process.exit(1);
        });
    } else {
        //workers should simply keep working...
        //fire off a new worker
        createWorker(worker.workerType);
    }

}
```