# How to send input to child process created with spawn? nodejs

Tags: node.js

I'm running Windows 10, and I have a program, let's call it `program`, that can be run from the command line.  When run, it responds to commands the user enters.  The user enters a command, presses the return key, and the program prints a response.  I did not make this program and do not have the source, so I cannot modify it.

I want to run this program from within Node.js, and have my Node.js program act as the user, sending it commands and getting the responses.  I spawn my program like this:

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
var child = spawn('program');

child.stdout.on('data', function(data) {
    console.log(`stdout: ${data}`);
});
```

Then I attempt to send it a command, for example, `help`.

```
child.stdin.write("help\n");
```

And nothing happens.  If I manually run the program, type `help`, and press the return key, I get output.  I want Node.js to run the program, send it input, and receive the output exactly as a human user would.  I assumed that `stdin.write()` would send the program a command as if the user typed it in the console.  However, as the program does not respond, I assume this is not the case.  How can I send the program input?

I've seen many similar questions, but unfortunately the solutions their authors report as "working" did not work for me.

- [Sending input data to child process in node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27051116/)

  I've seen this question and answer and tried everything in it with no success.  I've tried ending the command with `\r\n` instead of `\n`.  I've also tried adding the line `child.stdin.end()` after writing.  Neither of these worked.
- [How to pass STDIN to node.js child process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37685461/)

  This person, in their self-answer, says that they got theirs to work almost exactly as I'm doing it, but mine does not work.
- [Nodejs Child Process: write to stdin from an already initialised process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13230370/)

  This person, in their self-answer, says they got it to work by writing their input to a file and then piping that file to `stdin`.  This sounds overly complicated to send a simple string.

Comment: Try the same with vim. I mean write this `var child = spawn('vim');` and `child.stdin.write("q\n");`. This should run `vim` and exit. Does it work?

Comment: just in case someone is using IPC and JSON serialization, what I observed is that it sends message from Child-to-Parent but not Parent-to-Child using `send()` function. When I used `fork` instead of `spawn`, it started sending messages in both ways.

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me, when running from Win10 CMD or Git Bash:

```js
console.log('Running child process...');
const spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
const child = spawn('node');
// Also worked, from Git Bash:
//const child = spawn('cat');

child.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
    console.log(`stdout: "${data}"`);
});

child.stdin.write("console.log('Hello!');\n");
child.stdin.end(); // EOF

child.on('close', (code) => {
    console.log(`Child process exited with code ${code}.`);
});
```

Result:

```
D:\Martin\dev\node>node test11.js
Running child process...
stdout: "Hello!
"
Child process exited with code 0.
```

I also tried running `aws configure` like this, first it didn't work because I sent only a single line. But when sending four lines for the expected four input values, it worked.

Maybe your program expects special properties for `stdin`, like being a real terminal, and therefore doesn't take your input?
Or did you forget to send the EOF using `child.stdin.end();`? (If you remove that call from my example, the child waits for input forever.)

Answer (score 2):

Here is what worked for me. I have used `child_process` `exec` to create a child process. Inside this child process `Promise`, I am handling the i/o part of the `cmd` given as parameter. Its' not perfect, but its working.

Sample function call where you dont need any human input.

```
executeCLI("cat ~/index.html");
```

Sample function call where you interact with aws cli. Here

```
executeCLI("aws configure --profile dev")
```

Code for custom `executeCLI` function.

```
var { exec } = require('child_process');
async function executeCLI(cmd) {
  console.log("About to execute this: ", cmd);
  var child = exec(cmd);
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    child.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
      console.log(`${data}`);
      process.stdin.pipe(child.stdin);
    });

    child.on('close', function (err, data) {
      if (err) {
        console.log("Error executing cmd: ", err);
        reject(err);
      } else {
        //   console.log("data:", data)
        resolve(data);
      }
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: how is this sending data to the spawned process? You simply exec a command. We are looking for a way to have the process running with spawn and then execute the command.

Comment: @TheFool When we pass the parameter "cmd" as a string var; we can pass any no of arguments or flags within the string. e.g given "aws configure --profile dev" or "/scripts/blabla.sh -a 1 -b 2"

Comment: you don't understand what im saying and you don't understand the question. Yes you do execute a command but you don't have the process running in the background first. You start the process, capture its output and end the process. That is NOT the question.

Comment: the answer by the way would be by child_process.spawn and then proc.write(data) at any time to the running process.

Answer (score -4):

Extract the user input code from browser and save that code into a file on your system using `fs` module. Let that file be '**program.cpp**' and save the user data input in a text file.

As we can compile our c++ code on our terminal using g++ similarly we will be using `child_process` to access our system terminal and run user's code.

[execFile](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_execfile_file_args_options_callback) can be used for executing our program

```
var { execFile } = require('child_process');

execFile("g++", ['program.cpp'], (err, stdout, stderr) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log("compilation error: ",err);
    } else{
        execFile ('./a.out' ,['<', 'input.txt'], {shell: true}, (err, stdout, stderr) => {
            console.log("output: ", stdout);         
        })
    }
})
```

In this code we simply require the `child_process` and uses its `execFile` function.

- First we compile the code present in **program.cpp**, which creates a default **a.out** as output file
- Then we pass the a.out file with input that is present in **input.txt**

Hence you can view the generated output in your terminal and pass that back to the user.

for more details you can check: [Child Processes](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html)